# How to create an optimized iterator for a long list of integers?

Tags: python, list, iterator, integer, listiterator

Say I have a very large list of integers that occupies a very large amount of memory. If the list's integers were in even increments, I could then easily express the list as an iterator occupying comparatively no memory. But with more complicated patterns, it would become more difficult to express this list as an iterator.

Is there a Python package that can analyze a list of integers and return an "optimized" iterator? Or methodologies I can look into to accomplish this?

Comment: What you're describing is a form of [compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression).

Comment: What about making an in-memory zip file?

Comment: I didn't even think about it like that. Do you know of any compression algorithms that allow accessing data in the compressed array by index beyond just compressing sequential duplicates?

Comment: how complicated a pattern? do you know a function that can always determine the next item in the list?

Comment: Look at the original LZW compression (a.k.a. GIF).

Comment: This is a complex question. Whether or not there is 'useful' (that is, short) closed form solution for a particular pattern of integers is a question of number theory that can be hard to answer precisely. Depending on your particular list, it might be trivial - or impossible. Looking into general purpose compression as mentioned above could be helpful. What are you trying to accomplish? Are you just curious? (Nothing wrong with that!)

Comment: I'm mainly just curious. However, to give context, I was thinking up ways to reduce the data storage requirements of large sparse matrices, particularly for sparse matrix vector products. Here, the list of integers would be indexes pointing a reduced list of nonzero elements and also element location. The LZW compression looks very neat. I'll read up on that.

Comment: Are you asking for example, given a iterable `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, ...]`, have a "generator" `g` that infers the algorithm (for each position `i`, return `2^i+1 - 1`), and stores the algorithm rather than the long list of numbers stored in memory?

Comment: You could google your sequence and hope to find it at `https://oeis.org/`. If you find it, you can compress your whole sequence to a small ID :)

Comment: Are the patterns known?

Comment: To add to @EricDuminil, PyOEIS might help.

Comment: It might be worth noting that expressing a sparse matrix using tuples of the form `(value, row, column)` is already a form of compression of some kind.

Comment: _"Say I have a very large list of integers"_ is not a sensible statement. How came that you and the Python interpreter got hold of that _very large list_? — did you _compute_ that list? if this is your use case, then you could use a generator if you need to access the list elements sequentially, a function if you need random access. In either case I cannot help because your question is obscure to me. My fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My proof of concept, using [lzma](https://docs.python.org/3/library/lzma.html) library ([backport for python 2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/backports.lzma)) with compression to memory. Instead of memory buffer you can use file on disk:

```
import io
import random
import struct
import sys

from backports import lzma

# Create array of integers with some duplicates
data = []
for i in xrange(0, 2000):
    data += [random.randint(-sys.maxint, sys.maxint)] * random.randint(0, 500)

print('Uncompressed: {}'.format(len(data)))
buff = io.BytesIO()

fmt = 'i'  # check https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters
lzma_writer = lzma.LZMAFile(buff, 'wb')
for i in data:
    lzma_writer.write(struct.pack(fmt, i))
lzma_writer.close()
print('Compressed: {}'.format(len(buff.getvalue())))

buff.seek(0)
lzma_reader = lzma.LZMAFile(buff, 'rb')

size_of = struct.calcsize(fmt)


def generate():
    r = lzma_reader.read(size_of)
    while len(r) != 0:
        yield struct.unpack(fmt, r)[0]
        r = lzma_reader.read(size_of)


# Test if it is same array
res = list(generate())
print res == data
```

Result:

```
Uncompressed: 496225
Compressed: 11568
True
```

Comment: An alternative form of compression I've found and used a while ago is the [SIMDComp](https://github.com/lemire/simdcomp) library.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Efron Licht, clearly: It entirely depends on complexity of particular list to compact (not to say 'compress'). Unless your lists are simple enought to express as generators, your only choice is to use Bartek Jablonski answer.

Answer (score -1):

A generator is what you are looking for. You can encapsulate all the custom logic inside. The question is a bit vague, so might help knowing if this aids you

```
def moreDataExists(index):
    # Your stop condition
    return True

def getNextIndex(index):
    # Your complicated pattern of going from one index to the next.
    return index

def generator(yourData):
    index = None
    while moreDataExists(index):
        index = getNextIndex(index)
        yield yourData[index]


for d in generator(data):
    doSomethingWith(d)
```

Answer (score -2):

This is very easy - just wrap your filtered iterator with a generator, e.g.:

```
for i in (_ for _ in range(int(1e7)) if str(_)==str(_)[::-1]):
    if str(i**2)==str(i**2)[::-1]:
        print(i)
```